pgadmin on K8s with Helm
I'm trying to deployg pgadmin on on-prem K8S using Helm and I did, however when I try to login Im getting Incorrect username or password. Unfortunately, while looking on env on pod, this variables are set properly:
/pgadmin4 $ env | grep PGADMIN
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://10.101.181.184:80
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=80
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@test.com
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_SERVICE_HOST=10.101.181.184
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_PORT=tcp://10.101.181.184:80
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_SERVICE_PORT=80
PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION=False
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=10.101.181.184
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
PGADMIN_PGADMIN4_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp

Im using this chart: https://github.com/rowanruseler/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/pgadmin4 and my manifest looks like that:
image:
  registry: my-registry
  repository: dpage/pgadmin4

env:
  email: test@test.com

service:
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: pgadmin

persistentVolume:
  storageClass: gold
  existingClaim: pgadmin-pvc

My PVC:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi 
  storageClassName: gold

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi 
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gold
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - NODE_NAME

and SC:
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gold
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
parameters:
  type: io1
  fsType: ext4
  encrypted: "true"
  iopsPerGB: "50"
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer


What can be wrong here or should I else add something else to be able to log in?

I can see for env.password, it says "Needed chart reinstall for apply changes". have you done it? helm install my-release runix/pgadmin4 --set env.password=SuperSecret

@ha36d yeah, I've just uninstalled my whole release, I got rid of env and tried to use default and still, incorrect username and password. Fun thing, when I just used K8S manifests instead of helm I was able to log in
